# Adding Columns using google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, import, formula, google-query-language

Is there a way I can add a total of a column if the numbers are imported from a different sheet with google sheets? and matching a pair of dates?

```
=SUMIFS($S$8:S47,$O$8:$O47,">="&T$51,$O$8:$O47,"<="&$V$51)
```

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely this is the issue of QUERY. query likes to "assume" the type of dataset (numeric/plain text) and 90% of time it assumes it wrongly so you either end up with empty columns or missing values. use in S6:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1nC7e8za4_SjIAbPsRv4loQ8CHinwcp0J43LcyG0qopM", "August 2022!i3:j45")
```

Comment: That does return a value of 0 with no errors.  But will not add.

Comment: =SUMIFS($P$7:P45,$O$7:$O45,">="&T$50,$O$7:$O45,"<="&$V$50) will work but it does not start adding until there is 4 entries put in.

Comment: @ChrisWeber can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4Qy12gOXRDZlpA4PQphRmer6WxRnMf0fg26bUSizWw/edit?usp=sharing